# Can someone explain the difference between "Version" and "Update Versions" in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm having an issue with IE11 and a Webdriver script that just quit working for (seemingly) no reason.

My local machine doesn't work. (Version: 11.162.10586.0, Update Versions: 11.0.29)
BrowserStack DOES work. (Version: 11.63.10586.0, Update Versions: 11.0.26)

I've looked online and cannot for the life of me find any webpage that explains the difference between these two version types.  As you can see, the above version(s) are different.  I'd like to know the difference, and hopefully help me not have to search for both version types.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

- Internet Explorer version 4.0 and later versions include an Update Versions line that lists all installed updates or hotfixes to the current version of Internet Explorer. Updates to Internet Explorer 4.01 Service Pack 2 or Internet Explorer 5.0 and later versions are listed by their corresponding Microsoft Knowledge Base article number.
- The version numbers of Internet Explorer in the list are based on the versions of Windows. The list numbers might be changed by the latest hotfix.
- The build number of Internet Explorer in the release version of Windows Vista is the same as in other versions.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/969393/information-about-internet-explorer-versions)

Answer (score 0):

So basically, the **Version** is the current browser version installed and the **Update Versions** is the version of a security pack installed for Internet Explorer. More you can check [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/explain-difference-between-version-and-update/3a993d17-d86f-40cc-afab-30515a138ad5).